# Mouse scroll up only work for 1 scroll and stop

Tags: mouse-scroll

I have  weird situation where mouse scroll up only works for 1 scroll. Mouse scroll down works amazing. Anyone has experience such thing?

I'm using Microsoft Mouse 4500 and Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Thank you.

Comment: Does it work properly with another mouse? With a trackpad?

Comment: Good idea, I currently has only 1 mouse, I'll try to get another mouse. Than k you Heynnema.

Comment: Thank you, heynnema, that was the problem. Broken mouse =(